# strings and ints in functions

Tags: c++, function

Im a newbie at C++ and im currently studying functions. Im having a hard time to make this code to work. I am using C++ with the `<cstdio>` library because my teacher wants me to use C++. The loophole was to use `<cstdio>` so the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

void letters(char name[], char discipline[])
{
    printf("type a name:\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("\n\ntype a discipline:\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &discipline);

    printf("\n\nname: %s\n\ndiscipline: %s", name, discipline);
}

void calcsum(int point1, int point2, int sum)
{   
    printf("\n\ntype a point:\n\n");
    scanf("%i", &point1);

    printf("\n\ntype a second point:\n\n");
    scanf("%i", &point2);

    sum = point1 + point2;
    printf("\n\nsum is: %i", sum);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char name[100];
    char discipline[100];
    int point1, point2, sum;

    letters(name, discipline);
    calcsum(point1, point2,sum);    

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine till it asks to type the discipline. When I type it asks to type the name and then an error tab appears. This is happening for all my code that involves `char` arrays with any other data type.

Comment: Well, You should use `std::string` instead of these raw strings and you are including `iostream` already so you should also use it i.e, replacing `printf` and `scanf` by `std::cout` and `std::cin` because it is c++ and not c

Comment: If you're supposed to use C++, then you probably aren't supposed to attempt writing C.

Comment: Teachers usually don't appreciate "loophole" solutions, so don't be surprised if you fail this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The loophole was to use `<cstdio>`

I am not sure if your teacher will be fond of your choice, but you didn't ask for that.

In

> ```
> printf("type a name:\n\n");
> scanf("%s", &name);
>
> printf("\n\ntype a discipline:\n\n");
> scanf("%s", &discipline);
> ```

`name` and `discipline` are pointers allready, you don't have to use the address-of operator `&` on them wenn passing them to `scanf()`.

Also, there is no reason to pass parameters to your functions `calcsum()` and `letters()` since you don't want to pass any data. Just define the variables they use inside the functions:

```
void letters()
{
    printf("type a name:\n\n");
    char name[100];
    scanf("%99s", &name);  // read 99 characters + terminating '\0' max

    printf("\n\ntype a discipline:\n\n");
    char discipline[100];
    scanf("%99s", &discipline);  // NEVER use "%s" with scanf without specifying
                                 // a maximum width for field to read.

    printf("\n\nname: %s\n\ndiscipline: %s", name, discipline);
}

void calcsum()
{  
    printf("\n\ntype a point:\n\n");
    int point1;
    scanf("%i", &point1);

    printf("\n\ntype a second point:\n\n");
    int point2;
    scanf("%i", &point2);

    int sum = point1 + point2;    
    printf("\n\nsum is: %i", sum);

}

int main()  // there is also no need of taking parameters if you don't use them
{
    letters();  // no parameters needed since you don't
    calcsum();  // want to pass values to these functions

    // return 0;  main defaults to return 0 if there is no return-statement.
}
```

Last but not least it should be mentioned, that all functions of the C++ standard library reside in the namespace `std` (or beneath). That goes for the inherited functions from the c standard library as well. So

```
printf( /* ... */ );
scanf( /* ... */ );
// etc
```

should actually be

```
std::printf( /* ... */ );
std::scanf( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: here says to avoid to comment something like "thank you", so to stick with that ima say great answer, damn you should be my teacher.

Comment: so i've learned many this with the corrected code above but when i run it in DEVC++ i get this error: 'name,discipline,point1,point2' was not declared in this scope. the redd line is there in the main function, letters and calcsum